# IsContract check - how to do it faster

Tags: etherscan

I have a very long list of ETH addresses and I need to determine which of them are EOA addresses and which are contracts. is there some fast method to do it?
I know that etherscan api has suitable endpoints for that, but it's not so fast. Alchemy does not have isContract or similar, as far as i know. Anyone know how to make such a check faster?

Answer (score 1):

web3.js provides a getcode function
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html?highlight=getCode#getcode

I think the fastest way would be to run your own node and check if the address has a 0x bytecode or not.

```
const bytecode = await web3.eth.getCode(address);
  if (bytecode === '0x') {
    console.log('EOA');
  } else {
    console.log('Contract');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Foundry test and run it on a fork, simple and efficient:

test/addresses.t.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;    
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract AddressesTest is Test {
    address[] addresses = [
        0x7713974908Be4BEd47172370115e8b1219F4A5f0,
        0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48,
        0xDa9CE944a37d218c3302F6B82a094844C6ECEb17
    ];

    function testAddresses() public view {
        for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            if (addresses[i].code.length != 0) {
                console.log(addresses[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run it with:

```
forge test -vv -f https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[YOUR_ALCHEMY_APP_KEY]
```

It will print the contracts found:

```
Running 1 test for test/addresses.t.sol:AddressesTest
[PASS] testAddresses() (gas: 20890)
Logs:
  0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
```